# Can't find customer attribute source model

Tags: eav, source-model

I have a module:

Model/SelectType.php

```
class NAME_CustomField_Model_SelectType
{
  public function toOptionArray()
  {
    return array(
      array('value' => '1', 'label' => '1'),
      array('value' => '2', 'label' => '2'),
      array('value' => '3', 'label' => '3'),
    );
  }
}
```

in my etc/config.xml I have:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <NAME_CustomField>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </NAME_CustomField>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <customfield>
                <class>NAME_CustomField_Model</class>
            </customfield>
        </models>
    </global>
...
```

Now, if I set in the DB (table: eav_attribute) source_model to: `customfield/selectType` it gives an error: Source model "customfield/selectType" not found.

**UPDATE:**
I've moved my file to: "`code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Source`" (for testing ofcourse) and changed the resource model to: `customer/customer_attribute_source_selecttype`
This works, so I think there is something in my /etc/*.xml that is wrong, but I can't seem to find what it would be... :-S

Comment: I'm *really* surprised that this would work in any place. I think that EAV source models are expected to implement `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Interface` and/or subclass `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract`.

Comment: Check in the backend `System > Config > Advanced` whether your module is in the list, if it is, then the `Module_Xml.xml` in `app/etc/modules` is loaded. Next check: make a typo in your `config.xml` if `display_errors` and developer mode is on, then you should see an error, if not `config.xml` is not loaded. If this all works, I have no idea, why the source model is not found.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please share the solution with us.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML looks correct — although if Magento's loading the class from the `Mage` namespace that may be because your XML hasn't been loaded into the global configuration tree (cached XML, incorrect `app/etc/modules` file).

Your best bet is to debug things at the point where Magento looks into the configuration for your new class name

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
public function getGroupedClassName($groupType, $classId, $groupRootNode=null)
{
    //..
    $config = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->{$group};
    $className = null;
    if (isset($config->rewrite->$class)) {
        $className = (string)$config->rewrite->$class;
    } else {
    //..
}
```

Figure out why Magento can't find your base classname in the XML configuration, and you'll have your problem solved.

Comment: thanks for your answer I will definitely try this, if the answer to my problem is worth mentioning I will mention it here.

Comment: @bvl Also, I generally avoid camel casing and inter-casing classnames like that (`SelectType`).  To easy for the autoloader to get confused about w/r/t to class case.

Comment: @bvl Any luck here?

Comment: no, not yet, but I actually think the camel casing is the issue...

Comment: @bvl Based on what you've posted, you have the correct information in place to make the camel-cased class work (correct class argument, correct filename).

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is here `"DB (table: eav_attribute) source_model to: customfield/selectType"` 
It should be `customField/selectType`

Comment: This is wrong. The module before the `/` must be the same as the node in the xml, so `customfield` is correct.